# TSQL Transaction behaviour with disconnected queries - dynamic SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, dynamic-sql

I have the below stored procedure, that dynamically calls a list of stored procedures. It's been in place for a few months and has been running fine (unfortunately my access to the server is pretty restricted so couldn't manage this any other way)

```
Alter Proc [Process].[UspLoad_LoadController]
(
  @HoursBetweenEachRun Int
)
As
Begin
--find all procedures that need to be updated
    Create Table [#ProcsToRun]
        (
          [PID] Int Identity(1 , 1)
        , [SchemaName] Varchar(150)
        , [ProcName] Varchar(150)
        );

    Insert  [#ProcsToRun]
            ( [SchemaName]
            , [ProcName]
            )
            Select  [s].[name]
                  , [p].[name]
            From    [sys].[procedures] [p]
                    Left Join [sys].[schemas] [s]
                        On [s].[schema_id] = [p].[schema_id]
            Where   [s].[name] = 'Process'
                    And [p].[name] Like 'UspUpdate%';

    Declare @MaxProcs Int
      , @CurrentProc Int = 1;

    Select  @MaxProcs = Max([PID])
    From    [#ProcsToRun];

    Declare @SQL Varchar(Max)
      , @SchemaName sysname
      , @ProcName sysname;

--run through each procedure, not caring if the count changes and only updating if there have been more than 23 hours since the last run
    While @CurrentProc <= @MaxProcs
        Begin
            Select  @SchemaName = [SchemaName]
                  , @ProcName = [ProcName]
            From    [#ProcsToRun]
            Where   [PID] = @CurrentProc;

            Select  @SQL = @SchemaName + '.' + @ProcName
                    + ' @PrevCheck = 0,@HoursBetweenUpdates = '
                    + Cast(@HoursBetweenEachRun As Varchar(5));

            Exec (@SQL);
            Set @CurrentProc = @CurrentProc + 1;
        End;
End;
Go
```

However, the environment this is running in occasionally suffers from communications errors, with the query being cancelled whilst it is still executing.

My question is - can I wrap the entire procedure with a transaction statement and if I can what would happen in the event of the query being terminated early?

```
BEGIN Tran Test
Exec [Process].[UspLoad_LoadController] @HoursBetweenEachRun = 1;
COMMIT TRANSACTION Test
```

What I want to happen would be for the transaction to be rolled back - would this cater for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it works,but you might have to see how many stored procs you have and impact of rollback.Normally you can use **Set XACT_ABORT ON** inside stored proc,but due to dynamic SQL,it wont have any effect..

Sample demo on how to wrap your proc

```
begin try
begin tran
exec usp_main
commit
end try
begin catch
rollback
end catch
```

some tests i did on trying to use XACT_ABORT with out any success.but wrapping your main proc in a tran and rolling back when any error occurs,rollback all stored procs too.

```
create table test2
(
id int)

create table test3
(
id int)



create proc usp_test2
as
begin
insert into test2
select 1
end


alter proc usp_test3
as
begin
insert into test3
select 1/0
end


alter proc usp_main
as
begin
set xact_abort on
declare @sql1 nvarchar(2000)
set @sql1='exec usp_test2'

declare @sql2 nvarchar(2000)
set @sql2='exec usp_test3'

exec (@sql1)
exec(@sql2)
end
```